# Why do I recieve the same output for the for each statement in xslt

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert xml files into JSON.  So far I have this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="batch">
<xsl:for-each select="//batchitem/materialcode">      
 {  
            "load_id" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/code"/>"
            "amount" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/amount"/>"
            "weighlistfactor" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/weighlistfactor"/>"
            "watercorrection" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/watercorrection"/>"
            "materialcode" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/sequence"/>"
            "code" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/deliverynote/code"/>"
            "materialcode" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/batchitems/batchitem/materialcode"/>"
            "materialname" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/batchitems/batchitem/materialname"/>"
    }
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<batch>
  <code>213768</code>
  <amount unit="m3">2.33</amount>
  <weighlistfactor>2.33</weighlistfactor>
  <watercorrection>-6</watercorrection>
  <sequence>7</sequence>
  <mixer>Menger</mixer>
  <deliverynote>
    <code>2130021903</code>
    <id>97756</id>
    <recipeinstance>NL9560</recipeinstance>
    <recipecode>111270</recipecode>
    <recipename>NCODE_1NHCPG57</recipename>
    <site>NL4101</site>
    <loadingpoint>NL41-01</loadingpoint>
    <date>2016-02-12</date>
    <plannedproductionstart>2016-02-12T12:15:04</plannedproductionstart>
    <start_datetime>2016-02-12T12:15:04</start_datetime>
    <end_datetime>2016-02-12T12:23:32</end_datetime>
    <amount unit="m3">7</amount>
    <manualbatched>No</manualbatched>
    <order>2130021903</order>
    <startloadmixer>2016-02-12T12:16:49</startloadmixer>
    <truck>
      <code>NLM9279</code>
    </truck>
    <product>
      <code></code>
      <name></name>
    </product>
  </deliverynote>
  <batchitems>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>108954</materialcode>
      <materialname>Rivierzand 0/4</materialname>
      <materialkind>sand</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>Z2</externalid>
        <hopper>28212</hopper>
        <hoppername>Zandweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">1920</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">1920</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">1925</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">4.4</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">2.625</density>
      <absorption unit="%">0.5</absorption>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>109677</materialcode>
      <materialname>Riviergrind 2/8</materialname>
      <materialkind>stone</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>G3</externalid>
        <hopper>28318</hopper>
        <hoppername>Grindweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">1890</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">1390</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">1400</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">4.4</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">2.58</density>
      <absorption unit="%">2</absorption>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60334949</materialcode>
      <materialname>CEM III/B 42,5 N</materialname>
      <materialkind>cement</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>C3a</externalid>
        <hopper>28386</hopper>
        <hoppername>Cementweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">465</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">465</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">460</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">2.95</density>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60334946</materialcode>
      <materialname>CEM I 52,5 R</materialname>
      <materialkind>cement</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>C4a</externalid>
        <hopper>28386</hopper>
        <hoppername>Cementweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">465</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">465</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">465</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">3.15</density>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60335044</materialcode>
      <materialname>Vliegas (met K-factor)</materialname>
      <materialkind>filler</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>C2</externalid>
        <hopper>28386</hopper>
        <hoppername>Cementweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">420</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">420</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">420</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">2.25</density>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60335001</materialcode>
      <materialname>Cugla MMV con. 25%</materialname>
      <materialkind>admixture</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>H2</externalid>
        <hopper>28760</hopper>
        <hoppername>Hulpstofweger 1</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">0.93</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">0.93</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">0.93</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">1.143</density>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60573193</materialcode>
      <materialname>Cugla LR-9400 con 30% SPL</materialname>
      <materialkind>admixture</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>H4</externalid>
        <hopper>28760</hopper>
        <hoppername>Hulpstofweger 1</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">9.97</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">9.97</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">9.97</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">1.053</density>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60719054</materialcode>
      <materialname>Bronwater</materialname>
      <materialkind>water</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>W1</externalid>
        <hopper>28603</hopper>
        <hoppername>Waterweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">280</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">170</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">164</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">1</density>
      <temperature unit="°C">1000</temperature>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>109678</materialcode>
      <materialname>Riviergrind 4/16</materialname>
      <materialkind>stone</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>G1</externalid>
        <hopper>28318</hopper>
        <hoppername>Grindweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">0</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">500</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">500</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">3.5</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">2.62</density>
      <absorption unit="%">1.8</absorption>
    </batchitem>
    <batchitem>
      <materialcode>60719054</materialcode>
      <materialname>Bronwater</materialname>
      <materialkind>water</materialkind>
      <bin>
        <externalid>W1</externalid>
        <hopper>28603</hopper>
        <hoppername>Waterweger</hoppername>
      </bin>
      <target unit="kg">0</target>
      <targetadjusted unit="kg">100</targetadjusted>
      <amount unit="kg">96</amount>
      <moisture unit="%">0</moisture>
      <density unit="kg/l">1</density>
      <temperature unit="°C">1000</temperature>
    </batchitem>
  </batchitems>
</batch>
```

My problem is that it prints off the same thing for each loop.  I only prints off the first thing it comes across and does that repeatedly.  [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_for-each_title) is an example of what I was going for and I can't distingusish a difference.

Comment: You have `materialcode` twice: once as a label for `sequence` and once for `materialcode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only prints off the first thing it comes across and does that
>   repeatedly.

It does that because you are selecting the same thing repeatedly.

An XPath expression that begins with `//` selects all the referenced nodes in the entire document, starting from the root. And (in XSLT 1.0) `xsl:value-of` returns the value of the first node in the selected set.

You did not post your expected result, so I can only guess you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="batch">
    <xsl:for-each select="//batchitem">      
 {  
            "load_id" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/code"/>"
            "amount" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/amount"/>"
            "weighlistfactor" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/weighlistfactor"/>"
            "watercorrection" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/watercorrection"/>"
            "materialcode" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/sequence"/>"
            "code" : "<xsl:value-of select="//batch/deliverynote/code"/>"
            "materialcode" : "<xsl:value-of select="materialcode"/>"
            "materialname" : "<xsl:value-of select="materialname"/>"
    }
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

where the values of `materialcode` and `materialname` are retrieved by a **relative** Xpath expression, starting from the current `batchitem` node.